# Unable to share post using Facebook android SDK in Xamarin

Tags: facebook, xamarin.android

I am making an App using Xamarin PCL project type. I have made UI in my shared project i.e: In XAML. When I reached to share some post on Facebook using my Aap. I found out Facebook SDK of Xamarin for Common project is out dated and FB had changed its policy. After googling up I found that, I have to implement it in respective IOS and Driod project.

I have made a class named `FBLoginCustomView` that Inherited from `Button`.
I have written Renders in both IOS and Droid and add the custom button in XAML of my shared project in order to use 'FaceBook Login Button' on each platform through respective renderers.

In IOS, I have successfully completed the whole cycle.

In Droid, I am able to successfully logged In Facebook and got the Access Token. But unable to Share Post. I am calling the ShareApi using Dependency Service. Please review the Code below:

Renderer :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FBLoginCustomView), typeof(FBLoginRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.Android
{
    public class FBLoginRenderer : ViewRenderer<FBLoginCustomView, LoginButton>
    {

        LoginButton loginButton;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<FBLoginCustomView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var loginCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>
            {
                HandleSuccess = loginResult =>
                {
                    var accessToken = loginResult.AccessToken;
                    var accessToken2 = AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.Token;
                    AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken = accessToken;
                },
                HandleCancel = () =>
                {
                },
                HandleError = loginError =>
                {
                }
            };

            LoginManager.Instance.RegisterCallback(MainActivity.CallbackManager, loginCallback);

            loginButton = new LoginButton(Forms.Context);
            loginButton.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            loginButton.SetToolTipMode(LoginButton.ToolTipMode.NeverDisplay);
            loginButton.LoginBehavior = LoginBehavior.NativeOnly;

            //var permissions = new List<string> { "public_profile", "email" };
            var permissions = new List<string> { "publish_actions"};

            //loginButton.SetReadPermissions(permissions);
            loginButton.SetPublishPermissions(permissions);
            loginButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs ev) =>
            {
                var loginManager = LoginManager.Instance;
                loginManager.SetLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NativeOnly);
                if (loginManager != null)

                //if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken == null)
                    {
                        loginManager.LogInWithPublishPermissions(MainActivity.Instance(), permissions);

                        //loginManager.LogInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.Instance(), permissions);

                    }
                    //loginManager.LogInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.Instance(), permissions);
                };
            //loginButton.SetReadPermissions("public");

            SetNativeControl(loginButton);
        }

        public FBLoginRenderer()
        {
        }

    }

    class FacebookCallback<TResult> : Java.Lang.Object, IFacebookCallback where TResult : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public Action HandleCancel { get; set; }
        public Action<FacebookException> HandleError { get; set; }
        public Action<TResult> HandleSuccess { get; set; }

        public void OnCancel()
        {
            var c = HandleCancel;
            if (c != null)
                c();
        }

        public void OnError(FacebookException error)
        {
            var c = HandleError;
            if (c != null)
                c(error);
        }

        public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
            var c = HandleSuccess;
            if (c != null)
                c(result.JavaCast<TResult>());
        }
    }
}
```

Using Dependency Service in this Class:

```
namespace MyProject.Android
{
    public class FBshare_Android : Java.Lang.Object, IFBShare, TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener
    {
        TextToSpeech speaker; string toSpeak;
        //FacebookCallback<SharerResult> shareCallback;

        public FBshare_Android () {}

        public bool SharePost(string text, Image img)
        {
            PostPhoto();
            return true;
        }

        private void PostPhoto()
        {
            try
            {
                var image = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(null, Resource.Drawable.icon);
                var sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .SetBitmap(image).Build().JavaCast<SharePhoto>();

                var photos = new List<SharePhoto>();
                photos.Add(sharePhoto);

                var sharePhotoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .SetPhotos(photos).Build();

                if (HasPublishPermission())
                    ShareApi.Share(sharePhotoContent, null);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                SpeakToTest(exp.InnerException.ToString());
            }
        }

        bool HasPublishPermission ()
        {
            var accessToken = AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            return accessToken != null && accessToken.Permissions.Contains("publish_actions");
        }
```

When check CurrentAccessToken in watch, Theres a message instead of token written as:

[Access Token has been Removed, Permissions.....]

Once It logged In successfully, Then API should suppose to have Access Token. What causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented share for twitter and fb .

**Android version**

You can use native [facebook ShareDialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) and if isn't available use OAuth2Authenticator to get access token then post using [FB graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post)
and using OAuth1Authenticator for posing on twitter

```
public void ShareViaSocial(string serviceType, string urlToShare)
        {
            ShareDialog di = new ShareDialog(MainActivity.Instance);
             var facebookShareContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder();
             facebookShareContent.SetContentUrl(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(urlToShare));
            if (serviceType == "Facebook")
            {
                if (di.CanShow(facebookShareContent.Build(), ShareDialog.Mode.Automatic))
                {
                    di.Show(facebookShareContent.Build());
                }
                else
                {
                    var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                    clientId: 'ClientId',
                    scope: "public_profile,publish_actions",
                    authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
                    redirectUrl: new Uri( "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));

                    MainActivity.Instance.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(MainActivity.Instance.ApplicationContext));

                    auth.AllowCancel = true;
                    auth.Completed += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        if (e.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            Account fbAccount = e.Account;
                            Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "link", urlToShare } };
                            var requestUrl = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed");
                            var request = new OAuth2Request(SharedConstants.requestMethodPOST, requestUrl, dictionaryParameters, fbAccount);

                            request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(this.requestResult);
                        }
                        else { OnShare(this, ShareStatus.NotSuccessful); }
                    };
                    auth.Error += Auth_Error;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                var auth = new OAuth1Authenticator(
                               'TwitterConsumerKey',
                               'TwitterConsumerSecret',
                               new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"),
                               new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"),
                               new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"),
                               new Uri('TwitterCallBackUrl'));

                auth.AllowCancel = true;
                // auth.ShowUIErrors = false;
                // If authorization succeeds or is canceled, .Completed will be fired.
                auth.Completed += (s, e) =>
                {
                    // We presented the UI, so it's up to us to dismiss it.

                    if (e.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        Account twitterAccount = e.Account;
                        Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "status", urlToShare } };
                        var request = new OAuth1Request(SharedConstants.requestMethodPOST, new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"), dictionaryParameters, twitterAccount);
                        //for testing var request = new OAuth1Request("GET",new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json "),null, twitterAccount);
                        request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(this.requestResult);
                    }
                    else { OnShare(this, ShareStatus.NotSuccessful); }
                };
                auth.Error += Auth_Error;
                //auth.IsUsingNativeUI = true;
                MainActivity.Instance.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(MainActivity.Instance.ApplicationContext));
            }


        }
```